# Cypher - Find nodes which have more incoming than outgoing connections of a particular kind

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am modelling a transaction graph. This graph has

- nodes of label `User` with property

  - `id`
- relationship of label `TXN` with property

  - `id`
  - `asset_group_id`
  - `asset_id`

For a given user, I need to be able to find `asset_group_id` that they hold order by count of assets held in desc. Example output for a `User` with `id = 12`

| User | asset_group_id | assets_held |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 102 | 32 |
| 12 | 76 | 30 |
| 12 | 115 | 24 |

My dataset contains ~10K Users and ~300K relationships

### My approach

In order to do this, I need to find nodes which have more incoming relationships than outgoing. the diff of incoming and outgoing is held. (When they buy more and sell less)

there are also case where a User will just have incoming relationship for that asset_group_id and no outgoing relationship. (When they buy but dont sell)

### Cypher

The Cypher I have tried are following and none of them is close to what I expect. How do I prepare the query for this query

#### Query 1

```
MATCH
  (a:User{id:'12'})<-[t:TXN]-(:User)
WHERE
  t.asset_group_id IN ["category1", "category2"]
MATCH
  (a)-[t1:TXN{asset_group_id: t.asset_group_id}]->(:User)
WITH
  t, t1, COUNT(t) as inC, COUNT(t1) as outC
RETURN 
  t.asset_group_id, inC , outC,  inC - outC as held
ORDER by held DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This query is also very slow, and I don't think optimal for a large dataset.

#### Query 2

This Query is needed to find all cases where people buy and dont sell

```
MATCH
    (:User)-[r:TXN]->(b:User{id: '12'})
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
      (b)-[:TXN{asset_group_id: r.asset_group_id}]->(:User)
    )
  WITH
      r.asset_group_id as asset_group_id
RETURN owner
```

How do I write a better and optimised query. Ideally I would want to have a single query for this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match for relationships without providing a direction, and then calculate the counts conditionally, something like this:

```
MATCH
  (a:User{id:'12'})-[t:TXN]-(b:User)
WHERE
  t.asset_group_id IN ["category1", "category2"]
WITH
  t.asset_group_id AS asset_group_id, CASE WHEN startNode(t) = b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as inC, CASE WHEN startNode(t) = a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as outC
WITH 
  asset_group_id, SUM(inC) AS incomingCount, SUM(outC) AS outgoingCount
RETURN asset_group_id, incomingCount, outgoingCount, incomingCount - outgoingCount AS held
ORDER by held DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The correct query will include `END` in the clause. Like `SUM(CASE WHEN startNode(t) = b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inC,` . This always shows the `held` as `1`. Even though I know in DB thats not the case.

Comment: Yeah, I missed it. Updated the query, do check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines (not tested)

```
MATCH (seller:User)-[t:TXN]->(buyer:User)
WITH t.asset_group_id AS asset_group,
     [seller,buyer] AS parties,
     count(t) AS txns
UNWIND parties AS user
WITH user,asset_group,
     CASE WHEN user = parties[0] THEN txns * -1 ELSE txns END AS change
RETURN user, asset_group, sum(change) AS changes
```

In which `changes` would return 0 if there was no change, a negative if the user sold more that that he bought

Comment: This always returns the `changes` as `0`